# Estimate JS object storage size in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

What is the best way to estimate how much storage memory will json object (if JSon size in avaliable) will take in MongoDB? Is there some kind of correlation formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `Object.bsonsize()` method [mongo Shell Quick Reference / Miscellaneous](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous) .

It will give you the size of the object in BSON representation.

```
> Object.bsonsize({"_id" : ObjectId("51271c0c45fdc20bd005d1ef")})
22
> Object.bsonsize({"_id" : ObjectId("51271c0c45fdc20bd005d1ff")})
22
> Object.bsonsize({ "a" : 1, "b" : 2})
27
> Object.bsonsize({ "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "_id" : ObjectId("51271c0c45fdc20bd005d1ef") })
44
```

Remember that if your planning to let mongodb automatically assign ObjectId to your object it will cost the additional size.

Also the effective amount of space the object will take in the collection will be more than the size of your object because of padding mechanism.

Comment: what will be the additional size cost for each json object?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the actual document you can use it in mongo shell like so:

```
> Object.bsonsize(<yourdochere>)
```

This will give you the storage size of the document.